# NMap save results to separate files

Tags: nmap

I was wondering if there was any way to specify a range of IP addresses and save the scan results for each to a sepperate file in the same folder.

So scan 1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.2, 1.1.1.3 and they all save to a file with the file  name as their IP address in a folder.

I'm working on a small screen and it would really help make the results more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may very easily use a simple Python3 script that loops the range, calls nmap for every ip and saves it to different file.

Save this as `nmapper.py` and launch with `python3 nmapper.py`.
(If you don't have Python3 installed, you may want to rewrite this to bash or whatever you like.)

```
### just imports ###
import subprocess 
from netaddr import iter_iprange
### create range of IPs here ###
generator = iter_iprange('192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2', step=1)
### launch nmap for ∀ instance and save it as .txt ###
for ip in generator:         
    stdout = subprocess.getoutput("nmap " + str(ip))
    with open(str(ip)+".txt",'w') as f: f.write(stdout)
```

Comment: Wow what a great way to tackle the problem, is that actual Python code that will run or is just a guideline (not much Python knowledge)

Comment: I tested it, it's the actual code. If it works, don't forget to accept this answer; if it does not work, reply and we'll try to sort this out.

Comment: @Jacob2471 There are existing libraries ([Python 2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-libnmap), [Python 3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-nmap)) for running Nmap and parsing the results. Running a separate Nmap process for each target is inefficient and will be slow.

Comment: (Yes, nevertheless, as a quick solution, it may do. Jacob2471 may tweak it up or rewrite to bash or whatever if he doesn't like Python.)